# Methods to Defer Showing Product Price

Tags: cart, price, product-view

It is possible, with a stock Magento, to have the system hide a price from users until the product's been added to a cart?

If this isn't possible with stock Magento, is there known science for accomplishing this? ("known science" meaning third party extensions, proven and tested customization routes, etc)

Bonus Question: Does this (increasingly common) tactic have a name in the ecommerce industry?  (Googling has proven difficult since I don't know what to call this)

Comment: "Private shopping" would be the name to restrict a catalogue until registration. Not sure about hiding a price until cart. What's the use-case (ie. why hide the price) - it might help me understand better.

Comment: The hidden price is to get around MAP (Minimum Advertised Price) policies, specifically with companies that enforce them - Bose, Apple, Monster, Beats Audio, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hidden price" is to get around MAP (Minimum Advertised Price) policies, specifically with companies that enforce them - Bose, Apple, Monster, Beats Audio, etc.

**From Wikipedia on MAP policies:**

> Minimum advertised price or MAP (also known as resale price
>   maintenance, or RPM) is the practice of a manufacturer providing
>   marketing funds to a retailer contingent on the retailer advertising
>   an end customer price at or above a specified level. Such agreements
>   can be illegal in some countries when members and terms in the
>   agreement match predefined legal criteria.

For Magento - this is available natively in Magento Go:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/minimum-advertised-price/

Aheadworks has a Magento Connect module for this:

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/minimum-advertised-price.html

**Edit:**

**Magento Enterprise Edition** has built-in MAP support:

*In product detail admin:*

[image]

*In configuration settings System > Config > Sales:*

[image]

Thanks to @davidalger for pointing this out.

Comment: Magento Enterprise Edition also has support for MAP pricing.

Comment: @davidalger absolutely it does - ugh my brain sometimes...

Comment: Happens to the best of us… :)

Comment: Release Notes - Magento 1.6.0.0 (Aug 18, 2011)
Major Highlights

    Minimum Advertised Price